# Remove Left Recursion Grammar

Tags: recursion, compiler-construction, grammar

How can I remove the left recursions in the following grammar?

```
S -> “url” “(“ STRING “)” // basic services
| S “?” S // sequential execution
| S “|” S // concurrent execution
| “timeout” “(“ REAL “,” S “)” // timeout combinator
| “repeat” “(“ S “)” // repetition
| “stall” // nontermination
| “fail” // failure
```

Comment: Related (duplicate?) - [Removing Left Recursion Algorithm by Hand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720127/removing-left-recursion-algorithm-by-hand).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a parent production that is right recursive.

```
T -> S
T -> S "?" T // sequential execution
T -> S "|" T // concurrent execution

S -> “url” “(“ STRING “)” // basic services
| “timeout” “(“ REAL “,” S “)” // timeout combinator
| “repeat” “(“ S “)” // repetition
| “stall” // nontermination
| “fail” // failure
```

This will recognize the same set of inputs, but beware that T is now right associative, not left associative.